# OpsWorks Chef error in dokku deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, chef, opsworks

Everything worked fine until I resized one of our ec2 instances, now I'm getting this error in OpsWorks:

```
Exception: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: 
ruby_block[git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master] 
(dokku_deploy::default line 183) had an error: 
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
remote: -----> Setting config vars [K
remote:        GIT_REV: GITHASHKEY [K
remote:  [1G-----> Cleaning up... [K
remote: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? [K
remote: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? [K
remote:  [1G-----> Building api.website.com from herokuish... [K
remote: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? [K
remote: docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?. [K
remote: See 'docker run --help'. [K
remote: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host? [K
remote: /var/lib/dokku/core-plugins/available/common/functions: line 441: test: : integer expression expected [K
To dokku@localhost:api.website.com
 ! [remote rejected] deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@localhost:api.website.com'
```

Stacktrace snippet:

```
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20180301151623_3448-20180301151623/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.4.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:257:in `invalid!'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20180301151623_3448-20180301151623/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.4.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:244:in `error!'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/libraries/shellout.rb:9:in `shellout'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/dokku_deploy/recipes/default.rb:185:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'
```

I'm not sure if this an OpsWorks, Chef or Dokku issue.

Comment: I restarted the OpsWorks instance, now getting this error in logs: `ERROR: undefined method 'property' for #<Class:0x007fdf86d078f8>`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, there was a comment left in a .json file